# Retrieving data based on a sorted set of primary keys

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a set of primary keys. The set is sorted in the way the records are going to be displayed.

I want to retrive the records from the database in the same order as in the sorted set.

Currently I am doing like this:

```
  cursor getdata is
  select snr,    -- snr is the primary key
         field1,
         field2,
         field3
   from  MyTable,
         (select COLUMN_VALUE snr, rownum sort_key from TABLE(varray_of_snr)) snr_tab
   where MyTable.snr = snr_tab.snr
   order by snr_tab.sort_key;
```

The problem is that Oracle doesn't have to read the rows in the inner select in the same order as they are in the `varray`. There is no guarantee that Oracle won't read the rows in reverse order from the `varray` in the inner select.

Is there a simple way to guarantee that the sort order is preserved?

Comment: what's the problem? this query is slow? even if your varray contains hundreds of values, the sort will be fast. Are you sure that your query use the pk index? If it is slow, probably it scans fully the table.

Comment: The problem is that there is no guarantee that Oracle won't read the rows in reverse order from the varray in the inner select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

I created a global temporary table, `temp_snr_sort` with the columns `snr` and `sort_id`.
I then used the global temporary table to add a sort_id to my snr:s.

```
-- Load the array with sort information into temp_snr_tab
for i in 1..varray_of_snr.last loop
  insert into temp_snr_tab values (varray_of_snr(i), i);
end loop;

-- Get the data correctly sorted 
open getdata for
  select field1,
         field2,
         field3
    from MyTable,
         temp_snr_tab snr_tab
   where MyTable.snr = snr_tab.snr
   order by snr_tab.sort_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the ORDER of *any* data-set is never guaranteed unless an ORDER BY is specified.

If the order of the array is arbitrary, I'd recommend including a row_id field that is populated when you store the data.  `rownum` should only be used instead if you can *infer* the ordering and use an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: There are several sort orders, so storing the sort order permanently in the database is not an option.

Comment: Then you may be forced to store all the possible sort orders as addition fields.  You need to include enough data to be able to use ORDER BY to guarantee the order you require.  If you can update your question (or start a new one) with a much broader description of your real world problem, alternative approaches may be possible.  But to answer your specific question about guaranteed order; only ORDER BY can ever guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** Ok, an ideea (probably flawed :) )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE snr_type as OBJECT (
   id          number ,
   srn     number)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varray_of_snr AS VARRAY(10000) OF snr_type;
```

then create your varary putting in id your order

then order the main sql by id.

Comment: I get what you mean even though your example is flawed.

Comment: As far as I know, there is still no *guarantee* that the SELECT, in your FOR statement, will maintain the order of the array.  The only way that I know of, to guarantee order, is to specify an ORDER BY in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @Dems you're right, I should loop in the varray, not with a for :)

Comment: ouch, my ideea is the same as Dems.